# Route only Foreign traffic via OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tunnel, softether

I am running an OpenVPN Server via Softether on Ubuntu 22
I want to edit my client .ovpn config file so that the traffic going to servers hosted in my country bypass vpn and go direct (via domain TLD or IP list) and the traffic going to foreign country go through VPN connection.
is such thing possible ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.